# Common way of describing a "double-sided wait"

Tags: protocol, synchronous, rtl

Is there a commonly used name to describe a "double-sided wait" data transfer protocol?

This is a uni-directional scheme in which data is transferred on the clock edge if both the *sender* and the *receiver* (alternatively called *producer* and *consumer*) indicate that they are ready for the transfer by asserting a corresponding `ready` signal.  If only one side is ready for the transmission, it normally must enter a [*wait state*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wait_state).

"A Double-Sided Wait" is the title of a section describing this scheme in the book "Logic Design and Verification Using SystemVerilog" by Donald Thomas, but I don't find that name used elsewhere.

I believe that this is a very commonly used transaction protocol, but I don't know where to look for additional descriptive text on the topic -- or how to refer to it when trying to communicate about it.

Comment: so, something like  IEEE1284  PC asserts strobe, printer asserts ACK,

Comment: I can't see how a clock could be useful (unless the clock is only started afer both ends are ready), it seems the two ready signals should be enough.

Comment: @Jasen: IEEE1284 is conceptually similar, but a bit more complicated -- due especially to the fact that it is asynchronous.  In the scheme that I am thinking of, the producer and the consumer would be synchronized by a common clock signal anyway (e.g. inside an ASIC or FPGA), so the communication can proceed at a throughput of one item per clock cycle using only the two `ready` signals for pacing.

Comment: In Computer Science (cough), when two processes have to "meet" in some blocking interface to exchange data, that is called a "rendezvous".

Comment: @Kaz: The book does mention the term *rendezvous* in passing, but it is referring to a bit more general concept than the *double-sided wait*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One example of such a bus is the [AXI bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Microcontroller_Bus_Architecture), which originated with the ARM processor, but is increasingly being used as a standard interface for FPGA IP in general.

The two handshake signals are called TREADY and TVALID, and transfers only occur when both signals are asserted.

I don't know if there is a "standard" name for this protocol. On occasion, I have referred to it as "ready-enable" protocol in my own designs.

---

The more generic concept is "flow control", and there are many protocols that are used to implement flow control in various circumstances. The IEEE1284 printer protocol that somebody mentioned is an example of a 2-wire, 4-edge handshake that is often used for asynchronous communication at slower speeds. I have occasionally used such a protocol to transfer low-bandwidth data between clock domains inside an FPGA.

For higher-bandwidth transfers among clock domains, an asynchronous FIFO is often used, and its full/empty status signals become the flow control signals to the logic on both sides — and this is a very close fit with the TVALID/TREADY protocol of the AXI bus.